# Trying to start an IHP application but devenv and direnv are giving me errors

Tags: devenv, ihp, direnv

I just installed IHP into my Windows Subsystem for Linux and I have been trying to run the "devenv up" command, but it gives me multiple errors.

I will try to find any information about my system and laptop needed to answer this question.

When I cd to the application directory, direnv gives me the following message:

> direnv: PS1 cannot be exported. For more information see https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/PS1

I don't know if there is an issue in my system or the framework setup itself.

If I try to run the devenv up command anyway, the next error appears:

> error: experimental Nix feature 'nix-command' is disabled; add '--extra-experimental-features nix-command' to enable it

I tried to run the command with direnv uninstalled, but then devenv doesn't find any defined processes.

I am trying to follow the IHP guide to develop the application in this page of the ducomentation:
https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/your-first-project.html#starting-your-app

Answer (score 0):

The PS1 issue you link to should cover that issue. If you run `direnv allow` from your project directory you should be able to ignore that warning.

You can enable flakes by modifying your nix config. Try adding:

```
experimental-features = nix-command flakes
```

to e.g. `~/.config/nix/nix.conf`.

Then you should be able to start the dev server from your project directory:

```
nix develop --impure
devenv up
```